# How can i display the total no of books belonging to a rack?

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my table of books tbl_books

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_books` (
  `book_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `book_title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `book_author` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `book_year` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `book_rack` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`book_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;
```

Here is my second table of rack tbl_rack

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_rack` (
  `rack_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `rack_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`rack_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;
```

Problem which i want to solve:
I want to display all the data of rack in a table
Id       Name  Total no books in this rack ?
How can i display the total no of of books which are belongs to a specific rack..??/
Please help

[image]

Comment: You need a foreign key to link your tables.  http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp

Answer (score 0):

you can loop through your racks and count each book on that rack ( I take it tbl_books.book_rack = tbl_rack.rack_name and you know how to connect to your database with pdo and your connection is called $db)

```
    $rack = $db->query('select distinct rack_name from tbl_racks');
    $rack->execute(); $result = $rack->fetch_all('PDO::FETCH_ASSOC'); 

    foreach($result as $r){ 
        $books = $db->query('count(book_id) as num_books from tbl_books where book_rack = :book_rack');
        $books->execute(array("book_rack"=>$r['rack_name']));
        $b = $books->fetch('PDO::FETCH_ASSOC');
         echo $b['num_books']; 
     }
```